# Best way to return a user-generated file, AJAX or Forms?

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, submit

I'm new to web programming, so I need some help.

I am writing a custom file-creation app for my site. A user visits the page, clicks on some various options and toggles some checkboxes, and the presses a 'download now' link.

I have a PHP backend which will be processing the submission, and generating a PDF file. After the user presses the download link, I want the download to start like it would for any static link.

My question is: What is the best way to do this? From my limited understanding, I have a choice between using AJAX or somehow using forms to submit the data. What are the advantages/disadvantages of each? Does anyone have any good links to examples?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you cannot download a pdf via [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xmlhttprequest) (AJAX).

In general you should simply redirect the user to the resource that will generate the PDF with the proper [MIME type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME), and then leave it up to the browser to figure out how to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX will not work here, because you cannot use AJAX to download the file.

Instead, you should make a normal form, and have the PHP backend serve a file download when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a form. Ajax provides no benefits and a lot of complications under these circumstances. (You could use it, although you would have to use a non-XHR implementation, but it would be pointless to do so)